# Why can the anion NO3- behave as a L-type ligand while BF3 can not?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, halides

The fluorine has a lone pair, and the oxygen has a lone pair. Both are donate-able, so they should both act as ligands. I know fluorine is more electronegative, but oxygen is quite electronegative itself, so the reason must lie somewhere else.

Comment: Can (...) not behave? Could you correct your grammar to clarify?

Comment: Also they both can coordinate.

Comment: How in the world could $\ce{BF3}$ act as a ligand? Its the opposite of a Lewis base, a *Lewis acid* for that matter.

Comment: @Mithoron The definition of a ligand given to us is 'a species which tends to form dative bonds with transition metal ions', which is an L-type ligand ( I literally just read this off wikipedia, so not sure ). Can they both act as L-type ligands? The official answer disagrees.

Comment: Not bad searching @PrittBalagopal If BF3 coordinates to metal center accepting electrons it is also a ligand but "Z-type".

Comment: What’s an L-type ligand? Please edit your question to include that.